# Is it possible to get the actual size of the Camera Device and import it as a preview size?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making a project about Camera2API, usually by default it detect what the display size is and crop/cut the size using `MeasuredSpec`. My problem is that I don't know how to declare the actual camera hardware fully to get of what the camera actually see. Here is part of the code of what I am trying to do:

```
val cameraRes = Camera2BasicFragment().configureTransform(width, height) as Size
val cameraWidth = cameraRes.width
val cameraHeight = cameraRes.height
```

My aim is to make the camera hardware on any device literally and import it as a preview size, in order to make calculations of the crop/cut mechanism. I would be happy to get some help or conclusion whether or not, if it's true or not and avoid to be stretched in Portrait, in Landscape it doesn't stretch the `TextureView`, but on Portrait is squeezed or stretched completely. Here is the entire code:

```
class AutoFitTextureView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : TextureView(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    //private val SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE: CameraCharacteristics.Key<SizeF>? = null
    private val TAG: String = "Camera2APIPreviewResolution"
    private var ratioWidth = 0 //Width for preview
    private var ratioHeight = 0 //Height for preview

    fun nodAspectRatio(width: Int, height: Int) {
        if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.")
        }

        val cameraRes = Camera2BasicFragment().configureTransform(width, height) as Size
        val cameraWidth = cameraRes.width
        val cameraHeight = cameraRes.height

        val size = Point(width, height)
        val windowManager: WindowManager = context.getSystemService(Service.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        val display: Display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
        display.getRealSize(size)
        val displayWidth = size.x
        val displayHeight = size.y

        ratioWidth = width
        ratioHeight = height

        if (cameraWidth < cameraHeight) {
            height != width
        }

        val coefWidth = displayWidth
        val coefHeight = displayHeight

        if (coefWidth < coefHeight) {
            ratioWidth = displayWidth
            ratioHeight = displayHeight * coefWidth

            if (ratioHeight > displayHeight) {
                ratioHeight - displayHeight
            }
        } else {
            ratioWidth = displayWidth
            ratioHeight = displayHeight

            if (ratioWidth > displayWidth) {
                ratioWidth - displayWidth
            }
        }

        Log.d("Camera2APICamera", "width:$cameraWidth, height:$cameraHeight")
        Log.d("Camera2APIDisplay", "width:$displayWidth, height:$displayHeight")
        Log.d("Camera2APICoef", "width:$coefWidth, height:$coefHeight")
        Log.d("Camera2APIResolution", "width:$ratioWidth, height:$ratioHeight")

        requestLayout()

    }

@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)

        val width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)
        val height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)

        if (ratioWidth == 0 || ratioHeight == 0) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height)
            /**It's forced stretched when either width or height are 0*/
        } else {
            /** This is made for calculation formula if width is less than the height as calculated and another if statement provided the Portrait and Landscape*/
            if (width < height * ratioWidth / ratioHeight) {
                setMeasuredDimension(width, width * ratioHeight / ratioWidth)
            } else {
                setMeasuredDimension(height * ratioWidth / ratioHeight, height)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the message of the debug:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.camera2apikotlin4, PID: 18559
    java.lang.ClassCastException: kotlin.Unit cannot be cast to android.util.Size
        at com.example.camera2apikotlin4.AutoFitTextureView.nodAspectRatio(AutoFitTextureView.kt:35)
        at com.example.camera2apikotlin4.Camera2BasicFragment.setUpCameraOutputs(Camera2BasicFragment.kt:364)
        at com.example.camera2apikotlin4.Camera2BasicFragment.openCamera(Camera2BasicFragment.kt:422)
        at com.example.camera2apikotlin4.Camera2BasicFragment.access$openCamera(Camera2BasicFragment.kt:33)
        at com.example.camera2apikotlin4.Camera2BasicFragment$surfaceTextureListener$1.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(Camera2BasicFragment.kt:44)
```

Comment: The error clearly states that the addition ` as Size` is wrong. As the code of `com.example.camera2apikotlin4.Camera2BasicFragment` does not belong to the Android API it is unknown what type `configureTransform` returns.

Comment: @Robert ```configureTransform(viewWidth: Int, viewHeight: Int)``` Comes from a different Kotlin class, the method is public and the type is Int and returns Int. Yes I know it clearly states that the addition is completely wrong and won't succeed. So that's why I am looking for some other alternatives that I really don't know. I am sorry I am still learning of the Camera2API.

Comment: Then modify the code of Camera2BasicFragment instead of just using it. This fragment is not the Camera2API. If you don't look how it works internally you will never learn the Camera2API.

Comment: https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/kotlinApp/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.kt I looked it up from here just now.